# Getting Django - [Errno 111] Connection refused error

Tags: python, django, django-mailer

when Im trying to verify user registration via email its showing [Errno 111] Connection refused error in production but works fine in localhost
**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'xxx'
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
        user.save()

        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = 'Activate Your CaringHand Account'
        message = render_to_string('emails/account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        user.email_user(subject, message)
        messages.success(request, ('Please Confirm your email to complete registration.'))
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**error**

```
ConnectionRefusedError at /members/register/
```

[Errno 111] Connection refused

please help